# Hyperledger Fabric: How to get performance difference in LevelDB using I/O-bound transaction based on HDD/SSD?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, leveldb

I am currently developing a fabric chaincode.

I created a function in the chaincode that was I/O-bound (reading many values ​​from the ledger).

Experiment with this on two nodes. One node uses HDD and the other node uses SSD.

In the ledger, 10,000 objects with 4k size keys were stored. (It seems to be too small.. When I put 100,000, an error occurred, so I tested it with 10,000.)

If I READ(GetState) a lot of values ​​in the ledger, I expected that the READ speed of the node using SSD would be faster, but there was no difference.

I understood that LevelDB is a key-value storage, so there is no difference because it is fast. (Sequential and random reads have similar execution times)

Wondering how to experiment so that the difference in performance of HDD/SDD appears using LevelDB.

And if there is a way, I would like to ask for advice.

Comment: What was the error when testing with 100K records?

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying data via chain code, it is unlikely that you will be I/O bound at the disk level.  The path length for querying data via chaincode has a few hops so that is likely going to be your constraint.